# Is it possible to find local network devices in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, local-network

I have an application requirement to find local network devices like their following info:

```
{
    ip: 192.168.10.1,
    mac: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
},
{
    ip: 192.168.10.2,
    mac: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
},
{
    ip: 192.168.10.3,
    mac: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
}
```

I have tried different `npm packages` but couldn't do that.

Please guide!!!

Comment: As I understand you want to detect connected devices in your network?

Comment: @westdabestdb yes, connected devices with the same network i.e. router

Comment: Since Angular is front-end framework, you cannot sniff the network. But what you can do is, you can use nodejs as backend and install [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libnmap), and create API points. Finally you can connect your frontend  to backend and see devices.

Comment: but when it comes to deployment, node.js is deployed to the server and then how angular will sniff the network. Am I wrong somewhere or not understanding or don't have knowledge of how it'll all work. Can you make it clear for me please

Comment: Angular wont sniff the network.

NodeJs(backend) sniffs the network => API <= Angular will display API results.

Basically your nodejs code will handle sniffing and API, and your angular will send http requests to those API points to retrieve the data from nodejs.

Comment: OK make me correct if I am wrong somewhere!!! Angular will send the request to the API to get the local network devices to this user and some piece code like [local-devices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-devices) in API will get the result. right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185350/discussion-between-westdabestdb-and-wasif).

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it would not be possible. 
Angular is frontend language delivered to a browser as a Javascript and HTML. 
Even the browser could not access the network information.

Comment: then how it can be possible? through electron app or entension may be?

Comment: Extensions, or “add-ons”, can often do these magical things. They can add onto the browser UI, process pages that the browser loads. They do all sorts of things. However, they are not the same thing as plugins; they affect the web browser itself, not really the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

Click this following link [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/json) to know the details.
This is an example data. You get the correct data while calling the api like this (below code)

```
  getDeviceDetails()
  {

    this.http.get('https://ipinfo.io/json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
     data => {
          console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: OK, I'll try it.

Comment: @WasiF After trying, tell me what result you got.

Comment: It gave me my public ip and info about network but I want users information that are connected to the router. So that I can interact with them.